# Live CD not writing

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, livedvd, live-environment

I'm trying to put a operating system live CD onto a flash drive but I keep getting an error saying something happened and could not finish writing on to the drive. I've used unetbootin, Ubuntu live CD maker and another genetic form of simular to Ubuntu's naive live CD maker. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete and exact text of the error message, the full filename of the .iso image you're trying to write, and what utility you mean by "another genetic form of simular to Ubuntu's naive live CD maker."

Answer (score 1):

Bad download and corrupt files or usb drive not good.
Reformat USB Drive, re-create usb drive media, if it fails use another usb drive, if it fails, re-download OS media and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Linux operating system or liveCD, you could try an another method.

1. [Install grub](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-grub2-on-usb-from-ubuntu-linux/) on your USB drive.
2. [Edit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive) /boot/grub/grub.cfg file

Comment: I thought of grub once but it's out of my scope of abilities.

Comment: Above link will take you to the detailed step by step instructions. Once you get there, USB will become so handy and you can directly put ISO image to boot into.

Comment: Will I still be able to install it on my machine as well?

Comment: Why do you have to ask that?